# How to read the caption of a button in an Excel ribbon programmatically in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a third party ribbon installed in Excel 2010.

I want to be able to read the caption of the buttons in the ribbon. The caption, which can be either 'Pause' or 'Resume', indicates the state of a certain functionality.

The third-party add-in provider does not provide any mean to get this information via any API or macro. That's why I want to obtain this bit of information via the ribbon button.

**Edit**

I have attached the screen shot of the said addin.

[image]

I believe it is a COM plugin because I can print out the description with this VBA code snippet

```
Debug.Print Application.COMAddIns(i).Description  ' i is the loop index
```

Comment: Is the Button an OLE Object?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I have attached a screen shot to the question. It is a COM addin

Comment: Have you tried examining Application.COMAddins(4).Caption or what ever index corresponds to the object in question??  Or perhaps  .Label